# Have blender automatically monitor textures for changes?

Tags: texturing, uv, external-applications

Currently my workflow consists of photoshop on one monitor and Blender on the other. Whenever I save in Photoshop, I have to manually switch to blender and do Alt-R to reload the texture which can be quite annoying.

Is it possible to have Blender monitor the files for changes and automatically refresh the textures whenever changes are detected? This would make my workflow a lot more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Blender doesn't have this kind of feature (or at least I never heard of it). A quick google search however brought this as a result:

[External Paint Autorefresh](https://sites.google.com/site/pointatstuffweb/external-paint-autorefresh)

I haven't tried it but it surely sounds interesting...